# Module pattern: object literals vs self executed functions

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, javascript

I've seen there are two ways of implementing the modular pattern in javascript:

- Using object literals
- Using self executed functions (returning object)

I usually see more often the use of functions rather than objects for this purpose.

Is there any advantage on it besides the one of hiding some private functions from outside?

**Using self executed functions:**  (returning object)

```
var Module = (function () {
    var self = this;

    self.init = function () {
        self.someMethod();
    };

    self.someMethod = function () {
        $('#demo').on('click', function(){
            self.privateMethod();
        });
    };

    self.privateMethod = function () {
        console.log("aaa");
    };

    return {
        someMethod: someMethod,
        init:init
    };
})();

Module.init();
```

**Using object literals**

```
var Module = {    
    init: function(){
        this.someMethod();
        this.self = this;
    },

    someMethod: function(){
        var self = this;
        $('#demo').on('click', function(){
            console.log(this.id); 
            self.anotherMethod();
        });
    },

    anotherMethod: function(){
      console.log("aa");
    }
};

Module.init();
```

Comment: As I said: Is there any advantage on it **besides the one of hidding some private functions from outside?**

Comment: can use `new Module()` when it is a function so question boils down to use case

Comment: @charlietfl could you elaborate that a bit more?

Comment: can have different instances by using `new Module()` is the point. Assume you were storing values as well as methods, the values could be different in different instances